# how to delete the repeat lines in emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have a text with a lots of lines, my question is how to delete the repeat lines in emacs? using the command in emacs or elisp packages without external utils.

for example:

```
this is line a
this is line b
this is line a
```

to remove the 3rd line (same as 1st line)

```
this is line a
this is line b
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Put this code to your .emacs:

```
(defun uniq-lines (beg end)
  "Unique lines in region.
Called from a program, there are two arguments:
BEG and END (region to sort)."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region beg end)
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (while (not (eobp))
        (kill-line 1)
        (yank)
        (let ((next-line (point)))
          (while
              (re-search-forward
               (format "^%s" (regexp-quote (car kill-ring))) nil t)
            (replace-match "" nil nil))
          (goto-char next-line))))))
```

Usage:

```
M-x uniq-lines
```

Comment: Instead of using the kill-ring, you can just save the contents in a `let` bound variable.

Comment: ...Why use kill-line? This function makes the whole kill-ring a lot of useless items.

Answer (score 56):

If you have Emacs 24.4 or newer, the cleanest way to do it would be the new `delete-duplicate-lines` function. Note that

- this works on a region, not a buffer, so select the desired text first
- it maintains the relative order of the originals, killing the duplicates

For example, if your input is

```
test
dup
dup
one
two
one
three
one
test
five
```

`M-x delete-duplicate-lines` would make it

```
test
dup
one
two
three
five
```

You've the option of searching from backwards by prefixing it with the universal argument (`C-u`). The result would then be

```
dup
two
three
one
test
five
```

Credit goes to [emacsredux.com](http://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/03/01/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-delete-duplicate-lines/).

Other roundabout options, not giving quite the same result, available via Eshell:

1. `sort -u`; doesn't maintain the relative order of the originals
2. `uniq`; worse it needs its input to be sorted

Comment: `sort -u` may not be a stable sort, but `sort -u -s` is

Comment: @Squid I think I gave the last comment without verifying your's properly. Try feeding the input data to both `sort -u` and `sort -us`, you would get the same result which is not the same as `delete-duplicate-lines`'s. More to the point, we are not talking about stable sort, which means the relative order of identical elements are maintained. Since we're removing duplicates, identical elements are anyways lost. `delete-duplicate-lines` maintains the order of the originals not the duplicates; so one wouldn't be able to get the same result with `sort`.

Comment: Seems that `delete-duplicate-lines` now works also within a buffer, so no need to select a region first (`C-x h` for the whole buffer). At least with Emacs 26.2

Answer (score 13):

In linux, select region, and type

```
M-| uniq <RETURN>
```

The result without duplicates are in new buffer.

Comment: prefix it with C-u and it'll replace your region with the result of your shell command

Answer (score 2):

```
(defun unique-lines (start end)
  "This will remove all duplicating lines in the region.
Note empty lines count as duplicates of the empy line! All empy lines are 
removed sans the first one, which may be confusing!"
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((hash (make-hash-table :test #'equal)) (i -1))
    (dolist (s (split-string (buffer-substring-no-properties start end) "$" t)
               (let ((lines (make-vector (1+ i) nil)))
                 (maphash 
                  (lambda (key value) (setf (aref lines value) key))
                  hash)
                 (kill-region start end)
                 (insert (mapconcat #'identity lines "\n"))))
      (setq s                           ; because Emacs can't properly
                                        ; split lines :/
            (substring 
             s (position-if
                (lambda (x)
                  (not (or (char-equal ?\n x) (char-equal ?\r x)))) s)))
      (unless (gethash s hash)
        (setf (gethash s hash) (incf i))))))
```

An alternative:

- Will not use undo history to store matches.
- Will be in general faster (but if you are after ultimate speed - build a prefix tree).
- Has an effect of replacing all former newline characters, whatever they were with `\n` (UNIX-style). Which may be a bonus or a disadvantage, depending on your situation.
- You could make it a little bit better (faster), if you re-implement `split-string` in a way that it accepts characters instead of regular expression.

---

Somewhat longer, but, perhaps, a bit more efficient variant:

```
(defun split-string-chars (string chars &optional omit-nulls)
  (let ((separators (make-hash-table))
        (last 0)
        current
        result)
    (dolist (c chars) (setf (gethash c separators) t))
    (dotimes (i (length string)
                (progn
                 (when (< last i)
                   (push (substring string last i) result))
                 (reverse result)))
      (setq current (aref string i))
      (when (gethash current separators)
        (when (or (and (not omit-nulls) (= (1+ last) i))
                  (/= last i))
          (push (substring string last i) result))
        (setq last (1+ i))))))

(defun unique-lines (start end)
  "This will remove all duplicating lines in the region.
Note empty lines count as duplicates of the empy line! All empy lines are 
removed sans the first one, which may be confusing!"
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((hash (make-hash-table :test #'equal)) (i -1))
    (dolist (s (split-string-chars
                (buffer-substring-no-properties start end) '(?\n) t)
               (let ((lines (make-vector (1+ i) nil)))
                 (maphash 
                  (lambda (key value) (setf (aref lines value) key))
                  hash)
                 (kill-region start end)
                 (insert (mapconcat #'identity lines "\n"))))
      (unless (gethash s hash)
        (setf (gethash s hash) (incf i))))))
```

Comment: Lines in Emacs buffers are always delimited by \n (regardless of what delimiter is used in the corresponding file).  The use of \r for that was only ever for the old `selective-display`, which has been made obsolete many years ago by the `invisible` property of overlays and text-properties.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

1. Select a region of text.
2. Ctrl-U (prefix), M-| (shell-command-on-region), sort -u (the command to run on the selection and replace the selection with its output).