# List all requirable features

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is there a function in elisp which lists all features currently available in emacs?

By available feature, I mean all the symbols which can be used as arguments to `(require 'some-symbol)` without getting an error (even if they haven't been loaded yet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting question.  Well, let's say you just traverse your `load-path` and grep on something like `provide` - is that the list of "features" you're looking for?

```
(dolist (dirname load-path)
  (shell-command (concat "grep '\(provide' " dirname "/*.el") "tmp")
  (switch-to-buffer "tmp")
  (append-to-buffer "provided" (point-min) (point-max))
  (switch-to-buffer "provided"))


/Users/keith/.emacs.d/slime//hyperspec.el:(provide 'hyperspec)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/slime//slime-autoloads.el:  (provide 'slime-autoloads))
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/slime//slime.el:(provide 'slime)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/geiser-0.4/elisp//geiser-autodoc.el:(provide 'geiser-autodoc)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/geiser-0.4/elisp//geiser-base.el:(provide 'geiser-base)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/geiser-0.4/elisp//geiser-company.el:(provide 'geiser-company)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/geiser-0.4/elisp//geiser-compile.el:(provide 'geiser-compile)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/geiser-0.4/elisp//geiser-completion.el:(provide 'geiser-completion)
/Users/keith/.emacs.d/geiser-0.4/elisp//geiser-connection.el:(provide 'geiser-connection)
...
```

(Running this provided the bonus of showing me some obsolete directories in my own load-path).

EDIT: Here's a little version incorporating Bruce's and tripleee's suggestions:

```
(defun list-features ()
  (dolist (dirname load-path)
    (shell-command (concat "grep --no-filename --text '\(provide\\|\(autoload' " dirname "/*.(el|elc)") "tmp")
    (switch-to-buffer "tmp")
    (append-to-buffer "features" (point-min) (point-max)))
  ;; Remove duplicates from finding provided functions in both .el and .elc files
  (switch-to-buffer "features")
  (shell-command-on-region (point-min) (point-max) "sort -u" nil t nil nil))
```

Comment: Yes, that's the sort of thing I'm looking for.  However, note that you need to include compiled "elc" files in your grep, as some source files are not present as source.

Comment: Maybe also examine your autoloads? They might specify paths outside your load path. Of course, any code which manipulates the load path will still be missed.

Comment: @Bruce - good points. And correct on the excess concats (edited) - apparently I keep reverting back to other Lisp's in my head!

Comment: @tripleee - I think you're right - those functions would be available (and thus "features") but not actually loaded until called the first time. One could add/tailor another `grep` to include those.

Comment: Emacs has `sort-lines` but no exact equivalent of `sort -u`; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13046791/how-to-delete-the-repeat-lines-in-emacs

Answer (score 1):

There's a variable `features` that does exactly that.
`require` checks it on call. It's all in the doc.

Comment: The problem is that `features` lists everything that *has* been loaded. I need everything that *can* be loaded, even if it isn't loaded yet.

Comment: I was hoping there might be a way without manually navigating the load-path.

Comment: There's no such way. `features` lists what was provided. There's no way of listing all that can be provided
other than traversing the `load-path`. But Emacs doesn't do that for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Try the finder: interactively,

> C-h p runs the command finder-by-keyword, which is an interactive
>   autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `finder.el'.
>
> It is bound to C-h p, <f1> p, <help> p, <menu-bar> <help-menu>
>   <find-emacs-packages>.
>
> (finder-by-keyword)
>
> Find packages matching a given keyword.

or in code, access `finder-keywords-hash` after a `(load-library "finder-inf")`.

Comment: I actually need the list for code, not for interaction. But this helped a bit. I can compile a list of all packages with `finder-keywords-hash`.